# Popup on marker not working properly

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to assign a popup to marker.
I have created a popup and have bound it to a marker. However, it has not shown up.
I have test with an `alert()` which showed up, but the popup does not.

Can someone please help sovle this issue?

```
var lonLatMarker = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 78.447876 ,17.371610 )
.transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    );
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, lonLatMarker);
feature.closeBox = true;
feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble, {
    minSize: new OpenLayers.Size(300, 180)
} );
feature.data.popupContentHTML = 'Hello World';
feature.data.overflow = "hidden";

var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLatMarker);
marker.feature = feature;

var markerClick = function(evt) {
    if (this.popup == null) {
        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
        map.addPopup(this.popup);
        this.popup.show();
    } else {
        alert("Hello");
        this.popup.toggle();
    }
    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
};
marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);

markers.addMarker(marker);
map.setCenter (lonLatMarker, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

refering to the Openlayers documentation http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html#OpenLayers.Marker there is no proprienty called feature for marker object

so as I think you should remove this line

```
marker.feature = feature;
```

I had the same problem the click event on the marker didn't work and I solve it by this way